# Galois conjugation in $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, elliptic-curves

In Silverman's *Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*, he introduces the Weil pairing as a means of making the determinant pairing Galois invariant. He writes that $\det(P^{\sigma},Q^{\sigma})$ and $\det(P,Q)^{\sigma}$ need not be the same, where $\sigma \in G_{\overline{K}/K}$.

My question is this: How does $\det(P,Q)^{\sigma}$ even make sense when $\det(P,Q)$ lies in $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ and there is no natural action of the Galois group here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the answer by looking at the errata here: http://www.math.brown.edu/~jhs/AEC/AECErrata.pdf

Check out the modified page 93.  This is how I interpret it:

We know $\det(P^\sigma,Q^\sigma)$ means you take the determinant (using a certain basis) of the pair of points $P^\sigma$ and $Q^\sigma$, but $(P,Q)^\sigma$ apparently means you let $\sigma$ act on the basis you chose, and then take the determinant (since the determinant depends on the basis).

e.g. if your basis is $T_1, T_2$, and 
$$P = aT_1 + bT_2 = a'T_1^\sigma + b'T_2^\sigma,$$ 
$$P^\sigma = a''T_1 + b''T_2,$$ 
$$Q = cT_2 + dT_2 = c'T_1^\sigma + d'T_2^\sigma, \text{and}$$
$$Q^\sigma = c''T_1 + d''T_2,$$ 
then
$\det(P^\sigma,Q^\sigma) = a''d''-b''c'',$ while $\det(P,Q)^\sigma = a'd'-c'd'$.

Comment: It almost seems like a better notation would be $\det^\sigma(P,Q)$?